# Show Multiple Values in Drop Down list, CakePHP

Tags: forms, cakephp

I have a drop down list, which shows a list of 'Product Categories'

The problem is, that there are multiple product categories of the same name.

Each product category has an associated 'System', so my question is, is there a way to modify:

```
echo $this->Form->input('product_cat_id');
```

which shows `Product Category` to show `System >> Product Category`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.

I couldn't do it at view level easily, so I had to do it at controller level.

Basically, I was aiming to build options group that is used as below:

```
$options = array(
   'Group 1' => array(
      'Value 1' => 'Label 1',
      'Value 2' => 'Label 2'
   ),
   'Group 2' => array(
      'Value 3' => 'Label 3'
   )
);
echo $this->Form->select('field', $options);
```

I decided it'd be best to construct the options list in my controller and pass it to the view.

To that end, I added this code to my controller's action:

```
$systemCats = $this->Product->ProductCat->SystemCat->find('all');
$this->set('fieldOptions', buildFieldOptions($systemCats));
```

I created a function called buildFieldOptions which uses the fully associated $systemCats array as an argument:

```
function buildFieldOptions($productCats, $systemCats) {
    $optionsArray = array(); //empty options array
    foreach ($systemCats as $systemCat) {
        $productCatArray = array(); //empty product categories array
        foreach($systemCat['ProductCat'] as $productCat){  
            $productCatArray[$productCat['id']] = $productCat['title'];
            //fill product categories array
        }
        $optionsArray[$systemCat['SystemCat']['title']] = $productCatArray;
        //fill options array with system category as a key
    }
    return $optionsArray;
}
```

The completed one select box now has options such as below:

```
SystemCategory
    Product Category
    Product Category
    Product Category
SystemCategory
    Product Category
    Product Category
    Product Category
```

This works for me!